# Написание auto-complete на qt 5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, autocomplete

Добрый день! Пишу текстовый редактор на Qt 5 и столкнулся с проблемой. Проблема заключается в том, что не знаю, как написать auto-complete. Заранее благодарен!

Comment: autocmplete для какого виджета?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов кастомный QPlainTextEdit

Comment: Увы, для такого не делал. QCompleter посмотрите на всякий случай.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов QCompleter не получается связать с QPlainTextEdit, а с чем Вы работали?

Comment: QComboBox, вроде, был. Но с удивлением понял что не могу найти того кода :-/

Comment: @NEzyaka , метод 'QCompleter::setWidget()' пробовали? В справке в принципе указано, что любой виджет может быть использован для работы с 'QCompleter'.

Answer (score 2):

1. Берем каждое уникальное слово.
2. Заносим их в хэш-таблицу.
3. При вводе нового слова, читаем введеные символы и делает поиск в хеш-таблице.

Для оптимально решения данной задачи рекомендую "Книгу дракона".